# EF Core SQL Filter Translation

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 5.0.1 with ASP NET 5.0.1 Web API and I want to build a query with `PredicateBuilder` using `LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.2.1`

For the purposes of the question I simplified my model to:

```
public class User
{
    public long IdUser { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserDepartment> UserDepartments { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public long IdDepartament { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserDepartment> UsersDepartment { get; set; }
}

public UserDepartment
{
    public long IdUser { get; set; }
    public long IdDepartment { get; set; }
    public virtual Department { get; set; }
    public virtual User { get; set; }
}
```

One `User` can have many `Departaments` and one `Departament` can have many `Users`

Three models have its correspondent table in SQL Server and a `IEntityTypeConfiguration` class with the appropriate relationships set up.

All I want to achieve is to search any `User` that belongs to any `Departament`  which `Department.Name` is in a `List<String>`.

The `List<String>` contains a list of keywords, not the exact Department Name

`Department` table has this kind of rows:

| IdDepartment | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Administration |
| 2 | HHRR |
| 3 | Sales |
| 4 | Marketing |

And the `List<String>` can be any keyword like "Admin", "Sal", "Mark" and so on.

**First attempt**

... was to build a predicate like that:

```
List<string> kwDepartments = new List<String> {"mark","admin"};
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<User>(true);

predicate = predicate.And(x => x.UserDepartments.Where(y => kwDepartments.Any(c => y.Department.Name.Equals(c))).Any());
```

This produces a SQL with IN operator, like that:

```
...[t].[Name] IN (N'mark', N'admin'))
```

Obviously this is not what I want, but if I use `.Contains` instead of `.Equals`, an exception is thrown

> The LINQ expression could not be translated

I think this is because I'm trying to evaluate a non-primitive value.

**Second attempt**

... was to iterate over `kwDepartments` and add an `.Or` for each string, like that:

```
foreach (string dep in kwDepartments )
{
    predicateDep = predicateDep.Or(x => x.UserDepartments.Where(y=> y.Department.Name.Contains(dep)).Any());
}

predicate = predicate.And(predicateDep);
```

This returns the match that I expect, but two problems too.

1. The SQL translation is poor performance as EF Core anidates a `INNER JOIN` for each keyword. No matter  if `kwDepartment` has two or three elements, but with 100 or 1000 elements will be inadmissible.
2. Each `INNER JOIN` on `Departments` table have a `SELECT` with all the table fields and i did not need none of them. I've tried to put a `.Select(x=> x.Name)` statement in the predicate to take only two fields but it make no effect.

**Third attempt**

... was using Full Text Search using `EF.Functions.FreeText` but it seems to make no difference.

My goal is to build a predicate that translate in something similar to:

```
SELECT [c.IdUser]. [c.Name]
FROM [User] AS [c]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [UserDepartment] AS [u]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [c0].[IdDepartment], [c0].[Name] <--ONLY NEED TWO FIELDS INSTEAD OF ALL FIELDS
        FROM [Department] AS [c0]
               ) AS [t] ON [u].[IdDepartment] = [t].[IdDepartment]
    WHERE ([c].[IdUser] = [u].[IdUser]) AND ([t].[Name] like (N'admin%') or [t].[Name] like  (N'mark%')))
```

It is not mandatory to use the `LIKE` operator, but i put there for better understanding.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with `Or` predicate, but instead of multiple `Or` predicates on `user.UserDepatments.Any(single_match)` you should create single `Or` based predicate to be used inside the single `user.UserDepatments.Any(multi_or_match)`.

Something like this:

```
var departtmentPredicate = kwDepartments
    .Select(kw => Linq.Expr((Department d) => EF.Functions.Like(d.Name, "%" + kw + "%")))
    .Aggregate(PredicateBuilder.Or);
```

and then

```
predicate = predicate.And(u => u.UserDepartments
    .Select(ud => ud.Department) // navigate to department
    .AsQueryable() // to be able to use departtmentPredicate expression directly
    .Any(departtmentPredicate));
```

With that code and the sample list, `DbSet<User>().Where(predicate)` is translated to something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @__p_1 nvarchar(4000) = N'%mark%';
DECLARE @__p_2 nvarchar(4000) = N'%admin%';

SELECT [u].[IdUser], [u].[Name]
FROM [User] AS [u]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [UserDepartment] AS [u0]
    INNER JOIN [Department] AS [d] ON [u0].[IdDepartment] = [d].[IdDepartament]
    WHERE ([u].[IdUser] = [u0].[IdUser]) AND (([d].[Name] LIKE @__p_1) OR ([d].[Name] LIKE @__p_2)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ivan. Your solution works like a charm! :) Only one thing rest to be perfect. The SQL that produces your solution inlcude a SELECT with all fields (my UserDepartment model has 15 fields) in the INNER JOIN with UserDepartment that i don't need, only need IdDepartment and Name. Is there a way to only take these two fields from SQL?

Comment: Actually you can see that it joins the 2 tables w/o specifically selecting any fields,   note `select 1 from ...`

Comment: My fault, the extra fields are being retrieved because I have a extra query predicate on the IEntittypeConfiguration class. You're solution was perfect as is
Thank you again Ivan!